# Using Servant.Generic routes with ReaderT (Pool Connection) IO

Tags: haskell, servant

I was using `servant-generic-0.1.0.3` and `servant-server-0.13.0.1` to do the following:

```
data Site route = Site
  { page :: route :-
      "page" :> Capture "x" Int :> Capture "y" Int :> Get '[JSON] [Int]
  , home :: route :-
      Raw
  } deriving (Generic)

type API = ToServant (Site AsApi)

siteServer :: Pool Connection -> Site AsServer
siteServer pool = Site
  { page = \x y ->
      liftIO $ withResource pool $ \conn -> someDbFunction conn x y
  , home = serveDirectoryWebApp "static"
  }

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

app :: Pool Connection -> Application
app pool = serve api (toServant $ siteServer pool)
```

That worked fine, then I tried to use `ReaderT` to avoid passing `Pool Connection` to `siteServer`, so I added `AppM` and replaced `siteServer` like this:

```
type AppM = ReaderT (Pool Connection) IO

siteServer :: ServerT API AppM
siteServer = Site
  { page = do
      pool <- ask
      \x y ->
        liftIO $ withResource pool $ \conn -> someDbFunction conn x y
  , home = serveDirectoryWebApp "static"
  }
```

but I got a bunch of errors when I tried to compile it.

I followed the same steps shown in the [servant cookbook](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cookbook/using-custom-monad/UsingCustomMonad.html), but I couldn't make this work with generic routes, although it works when using regular routes.

Am I missing something that could make this work?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but you could try to look at server in this project template: https://github.com/Holmusk/three-layer/blob/master/src/Lib/Server.hs Also, `servant-generic` got merged to `servant-0.14` and API slightly changed. So be aware of this when you will bump up `servant` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the record-style routes supported by servant-* >= 0.14 (see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.14.1/docs/Servant-Server-Generic.html)), if you want to work with another monad than `Handler`, you will want to look at `AsServerT` and `genericServerT`.

Applied to your example, this means `siteServer` should be defined as follows (not typechecked, but should be very close to correct).

```
siteServer :: Site (AsServerT AppM)
siteServer = Site
  { page = ... something in AppM ...
  , home = ... something in AppM ...
  }

-- turning that into a usual chain of :<|>-separated handlers
oldStyleServer :: ServerT API AppM
oldStyleServer = genericServerT siteServer

-- bringing it all back in Handler
oldStyleServerInHandler :: Pool Connection -> Server API -- same as ServerT API Handler
oldStyleServerInHandler conns = hoistServer (Proxy @API) appToHandler oldStyleServer
  where appToHandler = liftIO . flip runReaderT conns
        -- or something along those lines

-- serving it
app :: Pool Connection -> Application
app conns = serve (Proxy @API) (oldStyleServerInHandler conns)
```

**Edit:** Since you're using servant-* < 0.14 with servant-generic, you should replace `genericServerT` with [`toServant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-generic-0.1.0.3/docs/Servant-Generic.html#v:toServant).

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just had to make `page` a top-level function and specify its type signature to avoid ambiguous type errors, do you know if it's possible to avoid turning it into a top-level function? Also I had to add `conns` as an parameter for `app` and pass it to `oldStyleServerInHandler`, and I replaced `genericServerT` with `toServant` to make it work with `servant-server-0.13.0.1`. `home` still doesn't work because it returns `Server Raw` (but this one might be the subject of another question).

Comment: For the ambiguous types, you probably need to give a type annotation somewhere just so that GHC knows the monad once and for all. For `conns`, yes sorry, I forgot to make it an argument of `app`. For `home` just try calling `Data.Tagged.retag` on the handler that serves the files, so that it is tagged with your monad instead of `Handler`. Or use `servant >= 0.14` where the file serving utilities are made polymorphic in the monad.